# pass VALID_PAGE(page) in page_alloc.c

Tags: linux-kernel, macros

I have faked a `struct page` in my user space into the kernel, but I can't pass the `VALID_PAGE` check in the kernel. It is defined like this:

- `#define VALID_PAGE(page)  ((page - mem_map) < max_mapnr)`

What does it mean? I have no idea `page - mem_map` is and `max_mapnr` is. How can my fake `page` pass this check?

Comment: Did you even try to search variables and their usage in the kernel code? E.g. [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c?v=3.6#L73) definition seems to be clear: `mem_map` is a arrat of pages, max_mapnr - maximum number of elements in that array. So, `VALID_PAGE` just checks that page belongs to given array of pages.

Comment: BTW, when talk about kernel internals(functions, macros,...) always specify kernel version. When talk about arch-specific code(under `arch/` or `asm/`) also specify architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mem_map is the global array of struct page, pfn is the key to index in the mem_map array .... (page - mem_map) will gives you the index of page in the mem_map array .... max_mapnr looks to be the valid index in mem_map. i hope  it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it helps. Is there any more reference on your answer?